# NumberFormatException - try/catch for parse value

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I am very new to Java and to programming. I am doing an exercise to print to console a multiplication tab. I wanted to check user selection. I have been looking for different stackoverflow previous posts which have helpt me a lot to go further. However when I test the program its throw Exception :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
> string: "p"   at
> java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
> at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)     at
> java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)  at
> TableMultiplication.main(TableMultiplication.java:18)

Please, could you tell me what am I missing ? The error message is asking me to create breakpoint. I do not understand it.

Thank you in advance

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class TableMultiplication {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int table = -1;
        boolean wrongSelection = true;
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Multiplication tab will be shown to console ");

        do{
            System.out.print("Enter the tab number you want, between 1 and 9 ");
            while (wrongSelection) {
                try {
                    String value = myObj.nextLine();
                    table = Integer.parseInt(value);
                    wrongSelection = false;
                }
                catch(InputMismatchException e){
                    System.out.println("Please, enter a number ");
                    myObj.nextLine();
                }
            }
        } while(table < 1 || table > 9);

        for(int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
            System.out.println(table + " x " + i + " = " + table * i);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you entered "p" as your input. Even though you used a try-catch-block, you didn't include the exception that [`Integer.parseInt(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) actually throws when the input string can not be parsed to an Integer - `NumberFormatException`. Therefore you don't catch this exception.

Comment: [`Scanner#nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) does not even throw `InputMismatchException` as I can see, why do you try to catch it here?

Comment: Hello @maloomeister I entered "p" to test my program. I wanted to see how does it work when there is an exception. As I wrote I am very beginner (started 2 weeks ago Java). Unbelieavable how people down votes for questions raised by beginners. Beginners questions doesn't mean no deep research has been done before.

Comment: @maloomeister I have understood that I mixed up between InputMismatchException and NumberFormatException

Comment: No worries, but did not downvote your question. For the future, check the references because they will always give you the most useful information.

Comment: Thank you @maloomeister. What do you mean about "references" ? Is it Java documentation ?

Comment: Yes exactly. For example the links I mentioned in my comments give you all the info you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are catching `InputMismatchException` but typing a letter instead of a number raise a `NumberFormatException`.

You can use a generic `catch`exception:

```java
try {
}
catch(Exception e){ //<-- Generic exception
}
```

Or use multiple catch block:

```java
try {
}
catch(InputMismatchException | NumberFormatException e ){ //<-- Multiple exceptions
}
```

Updated to explain why `InputMismatchException` doesn't work:

That's true that this `exception` check if the value read by the `Scanner` match with the type you want. But in your code you use `.nextLine()` method which expect a 'new line'.

These new line is a `String` and can be compound by letters, numbers... that's why the exception is not raised. The type match with the `scanner`.

If you want to check using only this `exception` you can use this:

```java
try {
    scanner.nextInt();
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {

}
```

Using this, if you type a `String` the exception will be raised because your `Scanner` expects an `int`.

Comment: Thank you very much that works. As I was reading on Internet I was thinking that InputMismatchExcept was working to check the input. I will learn the difference between both of them. Thanks again @J.F.

Comment: You are welcome. I have updated the answer to explain this, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
try {
                String value = myObj.nextLine();
                table = Integer.parseInt(value);
                wrongSelection = false;
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Please, enter a number ");
                myObj.nextLine();
            }
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Baungo. If I understand well if I just write Exception it will works for all specific Exceptions ?

Comment: Yes as all exceptions inherit from Exception you could always catch Exception. But that's also the reason why you should avoid it as far as possible, as it might hide other exceptions you don't expect. Like myObj.nextLine() could throw a NullPointerException in this example and you won't notice and assume an exception from Integer parsing.

Comment: In this case it would be much better to catch both exceptions like this: 

catch(NumberFormatException|InputMismatchException e)

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to input a String value that is not numerical, you will get the Exception of NumberFormatException. In your case, the exception means that you input a char of 'p' that can not parse to an integer value. If you input '1', '32', and 'a number that you want to input'; there will be passed.
There a catch block that only catches the InputMismatchException, but cannot catch other exceptions. You can also change the InputMismatchException to Exception, which is the parent to catch your other exception, like the NumberFormatException or others.